# C++ with Python No Module Named Encodings

Tags: python, c++

I'm currently trying to run this simple program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define PY_SSIZE_T_CLEAN
#ifdef _DEBUG
    #undef _DEBUG
    #include <python.h>
    #define _DEBUG
#else
    #include <python.h>
#endif

int main()
{
    Py_Initialize();
    Py_FinalizeEx();
    return 0;
}
```

But I get this error message:

Fatal Python error: initfsencoding: unable to load the file system codec
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'

I looked through many other posts online and most of them say to set the PYTHONPATH environment variable, which I did. I'm using Windows 10, Anaconda, and C++ Visual Studio.

I set the PATH variable on my computer to "C:/Anaconda/envs/myEnv" and "C:/Anaconda/envs/myEnv/Scripts".

Despite that, I still get the error.

Is there anything I'm missing? Can I try setting the PYTHONPATH variable at runtime?

I've also tried doing this:

```
_putenv_s("PYTHONPATH", "C:/Anaconda/envs/myEnv");
```

Comment: have you tried to set PYTHONPATH before running your program

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre do you mean within  C++? I've placed the put_env line in the beginning, yes but I still get the same error

Comment: I mean in the shell, before running the C++ program

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I'm running in Visual Studio though so I'm not using a shell. Would that still be relevant for me?

Comment: ok, system variables then. Then restart visual studio. Or run the executable from a terminal, with variable set

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I currently have the Python set under the "PATH" system variable. Should I manually create another "PYTHONPATH" system variable? Also, PYTHONPATH should point to where the python.exe file is right? Thanks for your help so far btw!

Comment: PYTHONPATH system variable should point to the directory where "encodings" module is.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I just added a PYTHONPATH system variable to "C:/Anaconda/envs/myEnv/Lib" since that's where I see the "encodings" directory, but I still get the same codec error. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Nevermind, I had to restart Visual Studio. I'm able to get the simple program running now. Thank you very much @Jean-FrançoisFabre. Do you know if I can do this programatically in C++ though?

Comment: I have no idea. sorry

Comment: I can't reproduce. You should probably use the same init/final functions (both with or both without the Ex suffix). I'd check the dll path of your c++ debugging environment first. PYTHONPATH won't come into play unless the python code tries to load other python modules.

Comment: maybe the system couldn't find the python path or module address or both.
if first happens you may add python path to system path environment.