# Cannot open file "python310_d.lib in visual studio"

Tags: opencl

```
#if !defined(MS_NO_COREDLL) && !defined(Py_NO_ENABLE_SHARED)
#       define Py_ENABLE_SHARED 1 /* standard symbol for shared library */
#       define MS_COREDLL       /* deprecated old symbol */
#endif /* !MS_NO_COREDLL && ... */

/*  All windows compilers that use this header support __declspec */
#define HAVE_DECLSPEC_DLL

/* For an MSVC DLL, we can nominate the .lib files used by extensions */
#ifdef MS_COREDLL
#       if !defined(Py_BUILD_CORE) && !defined(Py_BUILD_CORE_BUILTIN)
                /* not building the core - must be an ext */
#               if defined(_MSC_VER)
                        /* So MSVC users need not specify the .lib
                        file in their Makefile (other compilers are
                        generally taken care of by distutils.) */
#                       if defined(_DEBUG)
#                               pragma comment(lib,"python310_d.lib")
#                       elif defined(Py_LIMITED_API)
#                               pragma comment(lib,"python3.lib")
#                       else
#                               pragma comment(lib,"python310.lib")
#                       endif /* _DEBUG */
#               endif /* _MSC_VER */
#       endif /* Py_BUILD_CORE */
#endif /* MS_COREDLL */
```

This is the pyconfig.h. I searched alot from google and still cannot solve the problem. Linker->Input->Additional libraries all that also could not works. The following is my code

This seems to be a linker issue rather than a code issue and I'm not sure how to handle it. Really needs some helps. Thank You

Comment: did you install the debug libraries? [see here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/debugging-symbols-for-mixed-mode-c-cpp-python?view=vs-2022)

Comment: yes, thanks for your reply. I managed to do it later when i found this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66507618/running-python-matplotlibcpp-in-visual-studio-2019. I realize need to configure Properties -> Linker -> General & Input